# Scopus search: TITLE-ABS-KEY

Tags: database, boolean-logic, scopus

I realized something strange when searching on Scopus' database.

If I query some words in the field "TITLE-ABS-KEY", I do not get the same  results as if I query each field individually, separated by "OR"s.

For example, the query:

> TITLE-ABS-KEY ( flood  mitigation  dam  river  OR  stream )

finds **163** papers.

Whereas the query:

> TITLE ( flood  mitigation  dam  river  OR  stream )
>   OR  ABS ( flood  mitigation  dam  river  OR  stream )
>   OR  KEY ( flood  mitigation  dam
>   river  OR  stream )

finds only **140** papers.

Does anyone know if this is to be expected, and if so, what is the difference between both queries?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I eventually got a clarification from Elsevier Customer Service, and they provided the following explanation:

> "TITLE-ABS-KEY is going to find all results for any or all of those
>   three criteria with the keywords. TITLE OR ABS OR KEY is going to give
>   only results where three criteria don't overlap. So that would give
>   less results."

Answer (score 1):

I am not sure, but you could easily check by hand, since you have so few results (make a "difference" between the two results sets and see what's different in those 23 papers that are left).

The TITLE-ABS-KEY search takes the TITLE+ABSTRACT+KEYWORDS fields as whole, making those 3 fields into just one and then running a text search. Thus, if you have a paper that (as an example) has "flood mitigation dam" in its title and river in its keywords, that paper will be returned by the result.

The TITLE() OR ABS() or KEY() searches those 3 fields separately. Thus, the same example paper wouldn't be returned.

Hope this may help you. As said, you can easily check by hand what's going on...

Comment: hey, thanks for posting! my bad, I had gotten in the meantime some answer from customer service, and forgot to update my question here. Now done, see below for the explanation.